# Web Content radio buttons don't switch in Screen Time Family

Tags: macos, icloud, family-sharing, screen-time

As my daughter grows, I wanted to change the settings of **Content & Privacy Restrictions > Content Restrictions > Web Content**, from **Allowed Websites Only** to **Limit Adult Websites**.

But radio buttons don’t seem to work. It asks for the PIN, but after changing, two buttons are selected. It is the same on the child’s and parent's device.

[image: Screen Time settings]

I tried turning off ST, and restarting, and turning on again, but it looks like it gets back to Allowed Websites Only mode.

Is there a way to reset that without signing off iCloud?

PS: Also submitted with Feedback Assistant under FB9071145.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I fixed this issue. I had to use my iPhone:

- Go into your iPhone > Screentime > Family area (scroll down) > Select the family member with the rogue settings
- Turn Off Screen Time
- Turn Screen Time back on and set it up again (you can skip most of the settings, they will actually revert to what was saved last time on the MacBook you are trying to control)
- Change the setting for Content for the rogue radio buttons to what you want it to be
- Go back to the Macbook in question - view how the settings are now fixed!